# Python .drop does not give the result I expect

Tags: python, nan

I have a dataframe called `xxx`. One column of `xxx` is Final and `xxx` looks like this

```
  FpPropeTypCode DTE_DATE_DEATH             Area         Final  
0             FP            NaN  Ame_MidEast_Lnd           NaN  
1             FP            NaN  Southern_Europe  W.E.M. Lines  
2             FP            NaN              NaN           NaN  
3             ZP            NaN  Ame_MidEast_Lnd           NaN  
4             YY            NaN  Ame_MidEast_Lnd           NaN
```

I would like to remove all rows that has NaN for Final, so what I did was

`xxx= xxx.drop(pd.isnull(data_file_fp4['Final']))`

Unfortunately what I got is

```
  FpPropeTypCode DTE_DATE_DEATH             Area                         Final  
2             FP            NaN              NaN                           NaN  
3             ZP            NaN  Ame_MidEast_Lnd                           NaN  
4             YY            NaN  Ame_MidEast_Lnd                           NaN  
5             NN            NaN  Ame_MidEast_Lnd  NORTH ARM TRANSPORTATION LTD  
6             CP            NaN  Northern_Europe                     MPC Group
```

which is obviously not right...

What I actually need to do is to drop rows based on two conditions: Final being NaN and Area being Ame_MidEast_Lnd. So I can not really use dropna

What was wrong in my current codes just to do the first condition? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using pandas? Pandas has a function that will allow you to drop rows based on criteria, in this case a certain column being NaN:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

The specific command you're looking for would probably be something like:

```
xxx = xxx.dropna(axis=0, subset=['Final'])
```

axis=0 specifies that you want to drop rows and not columns
subset specifies that you want to drop where 'Final' is NaN

EDIT: The asker cannot use dropna because their filter logic is more complex.

If you want more complex logic, you might be better off just doing bracket logic. I will try and verify in a moment but can you try something like this:

```
xxx = xxx[~xxx['Final'].isnull()]
```

If you want the second part of the logic, where you have both the NaN filter and the column filter, you would do this:

```
xxx = xxx[~(xxx['Final'].isnull() & xxx['Area'].str.contains("Ame_MidEast_Lnd"))]
```

I have verified that this works by running this python file below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

xxx = pd.DataFrame([
                    ['FP', np.nan, 'Ame_MidEast_Lnd', np.nan],
                    ['FP', np.nan, 'Southern_Europe', 'W.E.M. Lines'],
                    ['FP', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                    ['ZP', np.nan, 'Ame_MidEast_Lnd', np.nan],
                    ['YY', np.nan, 'Ame_MidEast_Lnd', np.nan]],
                   columns=['FpPropeTypCode','DTE_DATE_DEATH','Area', 'Final']
                   )

# before
print xxx

# whatever rows have both 'Final' as NaN and 'Area' containing Ame_MidEast_Lnd, we do NOT want those rows
xxx = xxx[~(xxx['Final'].isnull() & xxx['Area'].str.contains("Ame_MidEast_Lnd"))]

# after
print xxx
```

You will see the solution works the way you want.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for help! What I actually need to do is to drop rows based on two conditions: Final being NaN and Area being Ame_MidEast_Lnd. So I can not really use dropna

Comment: Okay, give me a second to test something out.

Comment: @TingTing I believe I have a solution that handles both your isNull requirement and your column filter. Please let me know if that solves your issue.